# How can I install extras with `pip install git+ssh`?

Tags: python, git, pip, tox

I have an internal Python package which I install for `tox` with

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git
```

This works.

What does not work is to install the extra `server`.

### What I tried

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git[server]`
```

git clone failed with error code 128 (couldn't clone)

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git [server]
```

Cloning works, `Invalid requirement: '[server]'` (a parsing exception

```
pip install -e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo#egg=repo[server]
```

> Could not detect requirement name for 'git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

---

I think I might be affected by [this bug](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/181): [How can I install extras with `pip install git+ssh`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52717761/562769)

My (simplified) `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = begin,py35,py36,end

[testenv]
commands =
    pip install -e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo#egg=repo[server]
```

Comment: @9769953 See [setuptools' extras](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). Did you try to use `--install-option`? Maybe something like `--install-option="--extras-require=server"` might work...

Comment: You should pass the egg name for `pip` to be able to split the git url from the additional metadata. `pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git#egg=project[server]` will work.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thank you! I didn't know of `--install-option="--extras-require"`. I always installed extras via the bracket notation (e.g. `pip install requests[security]`).

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: @MartinThoma I did not post it as an answer before because I wasn't sure it would work (or whether `--extras-require` was the correct name). turns out they were consistent and my guess worked out :)

Comment: @hoefling It's not a duplicate. That question is a related but different issue and the answers are of no help (although I'd add that my answer would be a valid answer for that question too, so it would make sense to mark that question as a duplicate of this one ...)

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta it's the same one. One just has to read more than the question title (which, i admit, is kinda misleading with the `-e` option): _How can one manage to install extras_requires with pip when installing from a git repository?_ The answer listed there is also a working one and answers this question perfectly.

Comment: According to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/ `pip install git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomePackage[PDF]` should work ... but at least with ssh, it doesn't :-/

Comment: @MartinThoma can you provide the link to the repo? because AFAICT testing with my own forks runs fine, e.g. `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/hoefling/mypy.git#egg=mypy[dmypy]` installs the extra requirements just fine.

Comment: @hoefling No, it is a private repository. But I think I might have found the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52723919/562769

Comment: it's an issue with `tox` and not with `pip`. As correctly suggested in the comments to that question, wrapping the url in single quotes will solve the issue.

Comment: This question is the first Google hit for "pip git extras", is not exactly a duplicate of the other questions listed, and I think should be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--install-option` to forward options to `setuptools`, so the following should work:

```
pip install --install-option="--extras-require=server" git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git
```

See also:

```
$ pip install --help

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

[...]

Install Options:
  [...]
  --install-option <options>  Extra arguments to be supplied to the setup.py install command (use like --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin"). Use multiple --install-option options to pass multiple options to setup.py install. If you are
                              using an option with a directory path, be sure to use absolute path.
  --global-option <options>   Extra global options to be supplied to the setup.py call before the install command.
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. This does not work :-/ - it installs the base package, but not the extra "server".

Comment: Note that this one is different than passing extras in square brackets. When doing `pip install git+url#egg=name[extras]`, the extras are parsed and installed by `pip`, whereas passing an install option means that `pip` will ignore the extras and they will be managed by either `easy_install` (if `setuptools.setup` is used in the setup script) or by stdlib (`distutils.core.setup` case).

Comment: This can result in various installation errors because `--install-option` is propagated to extras (example: `pip install --install-option="--extras-require=dmypy" git+https://github.com/hoefling/mypy.git#egg=mypy` will fail with an error `Running setup.py install for typed-ast ... error: option --extras-require not recognized`), or to a situation where you are unable to uninstall dependencies because of the "old-and-unmanageable" install performed and `pip` refusing to uninstall with the message `It is a distutils installed project ...`.