# Does tox.ini need escaping for anchors in URLs (hash #)?

Tags: python, ini, tox

I have a tox.ini like this

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = begin,py35,py36,end

[testenv]
commands =
    pip install -e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo#egg=repo[server]
```

and I get the error

> Could not detect requirement name for 'git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

It looks very much as if the `#` is treated as a comment. Is that the case? How can I escape it?

### What I tried

- `\#`: The \ is recognized, but not the rest - so it is not an escape character
- Quoting the whole string: `ERROR: InvocationError: could not find executable 'pip install -e git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo.git#egg=repo[server]'`

Comment: Wild guess: Quote the string?

Comment: ...no, just the URL of course, not the *whole* string - i.e. "quoted argument"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess was to try quoting the URL:

```
[testenv]
commands =
    pip install -e "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/repo#egg=repo[server]"
```

and that seems to do the trick.